# Heroku unable to deploy python Pandas app

Tags: python, heroku, conda

folks. I recently wrote my first python Flask app, a simple data wrangling app that has the Pandas library as the only extra dependency (apart from Flask itself).

It retrieves data from online csv files, process them and return a few numbers inside a text. (I use no database. It takes the data from these online files and returns the result to the browser screen without storing it.)

I've built it within a conda environment for which I added only Pandas and Flask libraries. And it ran perfectly on my localhost.

But now I'm having a hard time trying to deploy it to Heroku...

First I generated my *Procfile* and a *requirements.txt* file using pip:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

But then, when I try to deploy the app, Heroku returns a series of errors related do "mkl" dependencies. I'm not sure if these are related to pandas, but here what they are: `mkl-service==2.3.0`, `mkl_fft==1.3.0` and `mkl_random==1.1.1`.

I tried to change the versions of the packs, choosing versions suggeted by Heroku, but it didn't work for `mkl-service`, which seems to be not supported at all by Heroku. I then just erased this line and took a chance. I managed to deploy the app with no error messages, but then the app doesn't run.

I also tried to generate my requirements.txr file through conda rather than pip.

```
conda list -e requirements.txt
```

It generates a weird file with "=" operators rather than "==", which I corrected through search/replace and deleting info on endcaps. This time, it also included `mkl==2020.2`, a dependency that has over 300 MB and didn't make my app work properly neither.

I wonder if the problem with my app has to do with some mess I did by mixing conda and pip for my environment. Or maybe it has to do with getting pandas to work online. I wonder if some of you might know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several combinations I managed to get the app to work by creating a *requirements.txt* that takes only the names of gunicorn and the packages I had originally installed in my local enviroment

```
Flask
pandas
gunicorn
```

Of course, Flask and pandas have their own dependencies, but it turns out Heroku automatically installs them, just like pip does. So, this time, making *requirements.txt* as simple as possible worked fine.